# error while installing squid

Tags: debian, squid

Im trying to install squid from official sites http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/ where I downoloaded squid-3.4.5.tat.gz.
I want to install it on Debian Jesssie.
Firstly I updated build-essential and libssl-dev.

```
#apt-get install build-essential
#apt-get install libssl-dev
#tar -xzf example.tar.gz
#cd example-name
#./configure –prefix=/usr/local /squid –enable-icap-client –enable-ssl –enable-ssl-crtd –with-default-user=squid
#make all
```

but after `make all` I got error:

```
In file included from ../include/MemPool.h:26:0,
                 from ../include/MemPoolChunked.h:4,
                 from MemPoolChunked.cc:87:
../include/splay.h: In member function 'SplayNode<V>* SplayNode<V>::splay(const FindValue&, int (*)(const FindValue&, const Value&)) const [with FindValue = MemChunk*; V = MemChunk*]':
../include/splay.h:212:5: error: nonnull argument 'this' compared to NULL [-Werror=nonnull-compare]
     if (this == NULL) {
     ^~
../include/splay.h: In member function 'SplayNode<V>* SplayNode<V>::remove(SplayNode<V>::Value, int (*)(const Value&, const Value&)) [with V = MemChunk*]':
../include/splay.h:151:5: error: nonnull argument 'this' compared to NULL [-Werror=nonnull-compare]
     if (this == NULL)
     ^~
../include/splay.h: In member function 'SplayNode<V>* SplayNode<V>::insert(SplayNode<V>::Value, int (*)(const Value&, const Value&)) [with V = MemChunk*]':
../include/splay.h:182:5: error: nonnull argument 'this' compared to NULL [-Werror=nonnull-compare]
     if (this == NULL) {
     ^~
../include/splay.h: In member function 'SplayNode<V>* SplayNode<V>::splay(const FindValue&, int (*)(const FindValue&, const Value&)) const [with FindValue = void*; V = MemChunk*]':
../include/splay.h:212:5: error: nonnull argument 'this' compared to NULL [-Werror=nonnull-compare]
     if (this == NULL) {
     ^~
MemPoolChunked.cc: In member function 'virtual void MemPoolChunked::clean(time_t)':
MemPoolChunked.cc:394:5: error: nonnull argument 'this' compared to NULL [-Werror=nonnull-compare]
     if (!this)
```

I was trying to google this problem, but I cant find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `squid` package is available on debian jessie repo: [`squid3 (3.4.8-6+deb8u4)`](https://packages.debian.org/fr/jessie/squid3) , you don't need to compile the program , just run:

```
apt update
apt build-dep squid3
apt install squid3
```